# Encrypt/Decrypt between VB2008 and Android

Tags: android, vb.net, encryption

I use these code to encrypt any plain text in vb2008.
I want decrypt and use generated file in my app in android.
I know that put files in assets folder and i use it.
this code use Cryptography to encryption.
how i can decrypt generated files in my android app.
and how i use them in my android app.
any idea?

```
Imports System.Security.Cryptography

Public NotInheritable Class Simple3Des

    Private TripleDes As New TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider

    Private Function TruncateHash(ByVal key As String, ByVal length As Integer) As Byte()

        Dim sha1 As New SHA1CryptoServiceProvider

        ' Hash the key.
        Dim keyBytes() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(key)
        Dim hash() As Byte = sha1.ComputeHash(keyBytes)

        ' Truncate or pad the hash.
        ReDim Preserve hash(length - 1)
        Return hash
    End Function

    Sub New(ByVal key As String)
        ' Initialize the crypto provider.
        TripleDes.Key = TruncateHash(key, TripleDes.KeySize \ 8)
        TripleDes.IV = TruncateHash("", TripleDes.BlockSize \ 8)
    End Sub

    Public Function EncryptData(ByVal plaintext As String) As String

        ' Convert the plaintext string to a byte array.
        Dim plaintextBytes() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(plaintext)

        ' Create the stream.
        Dim ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream
        ' Create the encoder to write to the stream.
        Dim encStream As New CryptoStream(ms, TripleDes.CreateEncryptor(), System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode.Write)

        ' Use the crypto stream to write the byte array to the stream.
         encStream.Write(plaintextBytes, 0, plaintextBytes.Length)
         encStream.FlushFinalBlock()

        ' Convert the encrypted stream to a printable string.
        Return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray)
    End Function

    Public Function DecryptData(ByVal encryptedtext As String) As String

        ' Convert the encrypted text string to a byte array.
        Dim encryptedBytes() As Byte = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedtext)

         ' Create the stream.
         Dim ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream
        ' Create the decoder to write to the stream.
        Dim decStream As New CryptoStream(ms, TripleDes.CreateDecryptor(), System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode.Write)

        ' Use the crypto stream to write the byte array to the stream.
        decStream.Write(encryptedBytes, 0, encryptedBytes.Length)
        decStream.FlushFinalBlock()

        ' Convert the plaintext stream to a string.
        Return System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray)
    End Function

    End Class
```

and in my form class

```
    Sub TestEncoding()
        Dim plainText As String = InputBox("Enter the plain text:")
        Dim password As String = InputBox("Enter the password:")

        Dim wrapper As New Simple3Des(password)
        Dim cipherText As String = wrapper.EncryptData(plainText)

        MsgBox("The cipher text is: " & cipherText)
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop & "\cipherText.txt", cipherText, False)
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This not specific to Android, you need to translate your code using Java JCE APIs. Basically you would

1. Use `MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1")` to get a SHA1 implementation
2. Hash you password to get the key bytes and the IV
3. Use something like `Cipher.getInstance("3DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding")` to get a 3DES implementation
4. Initialize the cipher for encryption using your key and IV using `Cipher.init()`
5. Encrypt your data using `Cipher.doFinal()`

You need to make sure you get the same key and IV as in VB first, then proceed with encryption. You seem to be hashing an empty string to get the IV in .NET, not sure what that gives you. Also check .NET documentation to check what the default padding for the `TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider` is.

Comment: i`m beginner in this and my code is copy from source code in a site. plz type sample fore me. thanks

Comment: You might want to read this first and try to put something together. Ask concrete questions when you get stuck. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html